# Differentiation of Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Let $F(x):=\int^{x}_{a} f(t)(x-t)\text{d}t$

Calculate $F^{\prime\prime}(x)$.

How can I start to do this question?

Comment: [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).

Comment: I presume $\;f\;$ is continuous...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fundamental theorem of calculus (when the function $f(t)$ is continuous):

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\left\{\int_\text{a}^xf(t)(x-t)\space\text{d}t\right\}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left\{\int_\text{a}^xf(t)\space\text{d}t\right\}=f(x)$$

Comment: The crucial step is to understand why $$\frac{d}{d x}\left\{\int_\text{a}^xf(t)(x-t)\space\text{d}t\right\}=\int_\text{a}^xf(t)\space\text{d}t$$ You do not even touch it.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the Fundamental Theorem of calculus: 
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left[ \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t)\ dt \right]= f(b(x))\cdot b'(x) - f(a(x))\cdot a'(x)
$$

Also know that "$x$ can be treated like a constant w.r.t $t$", that is
$$
\int_a^b x\cdot f(t)\ dt = x\int_a^b f(t)\ dt
$$

Use these two facts to write
$$
\int_a^x f(t)\cdot (x-t)\ dt = x \int_a^x f(t)\ dt - \int_a^x t\cdot f(t)\ dt
$$

Then compute the derivative w.r.t $x$ on the LHS by computing the derivative w.r.t $x$ on the RHS using the product rule and FTC.